# Make unit test return type StatusCodeResult

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have a test class that checks the put on a controller:

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory(Unit)]
public void DocumentController_Put_Returns_NoContent()
{
   // arrange
   var scope = new DefaultScope();
   var expectedId = scope.TestId;
   var model = Builder<Api.Document>
       .CreateNew()
       .Build();

   var entityToUpdate = scope.TestDocument;
   scope.DocumentProviderMock
   .Setup(x => x.GetAsync(expectedId))
   .ReturnsAsync(entityToUpdate);

   // act & assert
   scope.InstanceUnderTest.Put(scope.TestId, model)
   .AssertNoContent();
}
```

AssertNoContent is a method defined here:

```
public static StatusCodeResult AssertNoContent(this Task<IHttpActionResult> task)
{
    var httpActionResult = task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    var actionResult = httpActionResult as StatusCodeResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(actionResult, "IHttpActionResult is not the correct type.  Expected type {0}, but {1} was found.", typeof(StatusCodeResult).FullName, httpActionResult.GetType().FullName);
    return actionResult;
}
```

My issue is that the task is returning being passed in as a parameter is returning NegotiatedContentResult in the variable httpActionResult instead of the one I want (StatusCodeResult).

I am not allowed to change the AssertNoContent method. Why am I getting NegotiatedContentResult  and how do I get it to return a StatusCodeResult?

Edit (object not showing tooltip):

[image]

Comment: Why don't you set up some breakpoints into the call and then right click your unit tests and Debug them, you can then trace where the logic goes, and into what AssertNoContent method it goes? Also maybe StatusCodeResult is inherited in NegotiatedContentResult

Comment: Yeah, that what I've been doing. The statusCodeResult is null. What does that mean?

Comment: `httpActionResult as StatusCodeResult` will return null if it cannot be cast to that type.  Check the type on `httpActionResult`.

Comment: Result = "System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult`1[Web.Common.Common.SingularError]"

Comment: What @EvanL means to say is, put a breakpoint on that line and when it hits, mouse over the object `httpActionResult`, and it will show you what underlying object type it is (for all intents and purposes lets assume it can be anything - `String`, `Int32`, `SomeObjectType` etc.). Then you will need to go to the type and see if it inherits `StatusCodeResult` in order to be casted into one. AKA do you see `class SomeObjectType : StatusCodeResult` in its implementation?

Comment: Very strangely when I mouse over the object nothing appears. Everything else can be moused over and will show a tool tip. I'm attaching a pic for reference in the post.

Comment: Try copying `httpActionResult` into the watch window under the `Name` column.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what's happening here...your method is task.GetAwaiter().GetResult(), but I am assuming this method is async? So its not really going to both call it and wait to get the value back, probably, unless you use the `await` keyword...

Comment: Yes, I did that and am getting the error "Internal error in the expression evaluator". I have a new thread asking what to do about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890760/visual-studio-mouse-over-debugging-doesnt-work-for-particular-variable