# Visual Studio mouse over debugging doesn't work for particular variable

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, deb

I am trying to debug a controller and a particular variable does not show the tooltip. I tried restarting the computer and visual studio to no avail.

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Threading.Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromUri] Guid id, [FromBody] Api.Document documentModel)
    {
        var test = await PutOrStatusCodeAsync(documentModel, id).ConfigureAwait(true);
        return test;
    }
```

ALL other variables can be moused over:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

But not the one I need:

[image]

I added it to the watch list and am getting "Internal error in the expression evaluator".

I found this thread: [Get "Internal error in the expression evaluator" on "Add watch" function when trying to debug WCF service code (MSVS 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854426/get-internal-error-in-the-expression-evaluator-on-add-watch-function-when-tr), but my use Managed Compatibility Mode is greyed out!

[image]

I am running VS as an admin. HELP!

Comment: I'm just throwing out random ideas but are you sure that you don't need to do something like `var result = await (await firstFunction).secondFunction();`? I.E. Two awaits, also, any other logic inside those methods, should probably also need to be using await. Only way to check is to step through it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was grayed out because I was currently debugging. Once I stopped the process it was available to check.